# How to organize a search of nested objects with ElasticSearch?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, nested

I'm trying to organize search in my project with ElasticSearch but can't figure out one thing.

Let's simplify the context and assume that there are 2 models: Users and their Messages. So, I want to provide 2 types of search:

- find messages my text
- find users by their messages

## Messages by text (it is easy)

How it is supposed to work: user enters "notes about the meeting" and he gets a list of messages with this text.

Messages are stored in ElasticSearch like that:

```
{
  "id" : "1",
  "user_id" : "101",
  "text": "hello"
}
```

So, there are no problems to find messages by text.

## Users by text (problem)

How it is supposed to work: user enters "notes about the meeting" and he gets a list of users who wrote a messages with this text.

I have few ideas how to organize it, but I don't really like any of them.

### Idea 1

Find all the messages, extract their user_ids and then run SQL query like this

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN ('101', '102', '103')
```

It is the most obvious way but there is a question - how to organize proper pagination? Messages are paginated, but users are not.

### Idea 2

Store users in ElasticSearch with their messages as the nested objects:

```
{ 
  "id" : "101",
  "name" : "Bob",
  "messages" : [
    { "id" : "1", "text" : "hello" },
    { "id" : "2", "text" : "howdy?" },
    { "id" : "3", "text" : "bye" }
  ]
}
```

Now I can find users by just one query to ElasticSearch. But there are few disadvantages, too:

- I have to reindex whole user object when new message is added
- I have to duplicate messages in ElasticSearch cache to provide both types of search: first time as a separate message object and the second time as a nested object in the user object. I have a lot of data (at least 1 billion of messages), so this duplication will make my cache very large (and probably slow?).

Could you suggest me the best and the most common used way to solve this problem?

Comment: I would add the name of the user to the single message text document. If the only thing you are duplicating is the id and the name, I wouldn't worry. Also, if I'd have time and possibility I would test (like heavy testing) both approaches: yours `Idea 2` and `Idea 1` but where the document is like `{
  "id" : "1",
  "user_id" : "101", "name": "Bob",
  "text": "hello"
}`.

Comment: @AndreiStefan thanks for your response. It is not a problem to add user name to the message. But I still can't find out how to organize proper pagination of users in the case of using the first approach. For example, the search will return 5 messages of user A and 5 messages of user B, so the result will return only 2 users instead of first 10 users.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using aggregations. Indeed, at this moment you cannot paginate through aggregation results: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4915

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have indicated it can be solved by using nested objects but a better approach would be to use parent-child relation.

The issue you may face in nested objects can be solved by using [parent-child relationship](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/parent-child.html)(consider reading the whole section especially [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/parent-child-performance.html).) and use [has_child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-child-query.html) or [has_parent](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-parent-query.html) queries as per your need.

It will solve the issue of the need to index whole object. But you will need to take into consideration the memory as elasticsearch sores child document id in the memory(as of now).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As far as I see, parent-child relationship is better than nested objects in a case when quantity of children is 100-1000x times more than the quantity of parents, right?

Comment: It depends on your use case. You may choose to use parent-child relation for heavy but largely static parent data and small and more dynamic children data. The number of children doesn't matter that much.